# How to clear TextInput "placeholder" when user click on the input?

Tags: react-native, textinput

I would like to know how I can clear the "placeholder" in a TextInput when a user click on the field to fill it.

This is my TextInput:

```
 <TextInput 
   style={{height:40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth:1}}
   onChangeText={(text) => this.setStoreName(text)}
   value={this.state.storeName}
 />
```

And my constructor:

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { 
        name: "Votre nom", 
        storeName: "Le nom de votre commerce", 
        email: "Votre email", 
        address: "L'adresse de votre commerce", 
        city: "Votre ville", 
        category: "Categorie", 
        password: "Votre mot de passe"
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `placeholder` attribute with value [TextInput placeholder](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#placeholder)

```
<TextInput 
 style={{height:40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth:1}}
 onChangeText={(text) => this.setStoreName(text)}
 value={this.state.storeName}
 placeholder="Le nom de votre commerce"
/>
```

and in constructor

```
constructor(props) {
 super(props)
 this.state = { 
    name: "", 
    storeName: "", 
    email: "", 
    address: "", 
    city: "", 
    category: "", 
    password: ""
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `TextInput` like this:

```
constructor(props) {
 super(props)
 this.state = { 
    name: "", 
    storeName: "", 
    email: "", 
    address: "", 
    city: "", 
    category: "", 
    password: "",
    placeholder: "initial value"
 }
}    

   <TextInput 
     style={{height:40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth:1}}
     onChangeText={(text) => this.setStoreName(text)}
     value={this.state.storeName}
     placeholder={this.state.placeholder}
     onFocus={() => this.setState(placeholder: '')}
    />
```

Of course, it's better to define your functions outside of `render` function in the body of class and use them in the JSX.

Comment: once set to empty string ' ' it will never set 'initial value' again unless reloaded